# Using Attribute Rules to Pull in Attribution from Another Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, arcade, attribute-rules

I could use some assistance creating a calculation that just simply pulls attribution from a field in one feature class, and populates the edited result into another feature class's table.  For example:

We have a streets layer named 'Streets' with a field [StreetName].  When that table gets edited, the result should ideally just get updated in the other layer named 'New_Streets', but in a field called [NAME].  If these fields are in the same table - it works okay using this code:

```
var features = $feature.NAME

if ("$feature.StreetName" == "Null") {return false}

return features
```

I would like to be able to do this using two layers in the same geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough detail about the relationship of your layer *Streets* to *New_Streets*, thus I have to make an assumption that *New_Streets* is a copy of *Streets*. I say this as the solution I offer below requires a one-to-one match with the ObjectID field, so row 1000 in *Streets* is the same street as row 1000 in *New_Streets*.

So your data should look as below:

[image: Input data]

For this attribute rule to work you need to set an immediate  calculation to trigger on UPDATE for the Street layer. I show the setting of the rule below:

[image: Rule]

The expression is this:

```js
// Get updated name and ObjectID
var updatedName = $feature.StreetName;
var OID = $feature.OBJECTID;

// create a dictionary that holds the instructions to update New_Streets
var resultDict = {'edit':[{'className': 'New_Streets','updates':[{'objectID':OID,'attributes':{'Name':updatedName}}]}]};

// Returning dictionary executes update
return resultDict;
```

*Note: for some reason I had to enable GlobalID for it to work.*